# Python 3.2 and PyGTK

Tags: gui, gtk, python3.2

I want to learn to write programs using Python 3.2 and PyGTK (running on Ubnutu 11.04). The PyGTK module is installed for Python 2.7 by default but I would rather use 3.2. Is there any way to make this work?

Suggestions as to other tools to create GUI's with Python are certainly welcome, so far I have tinkered with Tkinter but would like to try something else.

Cheers.

Comment: "[We strongly recommend](https://live.gnome.org/PyGTK) not using PyGTK for new projects and to port existing applications from PyGTK to PyGObject."

Answer (score 0):

Install from source under 3.2.

```
python3.2 setup.py build
sudo python3.2 setup.py install
```

Comment: I tried this and all I got was:
`********************************************************************
* Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
* To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
********************************************************************
`
and I tried that but it didn't help me much as it didn't work (and it wanted to install for 2.7)